# How to show inertia data to Vue Componets?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs, laravel-9

In Vue Inspector I'm actually getting the message, But I'm not sure how to use it on Vue Components.

Please check out the image link

https://ibb.co/2KTmstS

I'm using Inertia helper method and sending a message to Vue Components but nothing working.

```
public function contact_to_project(){
    $message = "My message!";
    return Inertia('Contact_to_project', [
        'message' => $message
    ]);

}
```

My Vue Componets

```
<template> {{message}}</template>


<script>
  export default {
     props: {
        message: String,
     },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You're saying you just want to access the flash message without using a redirect?

Comment: @LinusJuhlin Thanks for your answer. I do not want to access the data using a flush message. I want to access it using the inertia render method and then access the props in Vue components.  I mean sending the data with render and then accessing it using props.
Like the first example shown here.
https://inertiajs.com/

Comment: I've added a new section to my answer called `Passing data with Inertia.js`, check it out and make sure that you have included all the parts of my code in your own to verify that it works.

Comment: @LinusJuhlin I don't see any difference. Still, I added your code and it does not work.I know it should work as per doc but somehow not working.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Download the vuejs dev tools and see if you can inspect the page to find out what is wrong. If you could update your post with all relevant files and leave nothing out. That would be helpful.

Comment: @LinusJuhlin I've updated the question .Please check

Comment: Your questions is too broad and you are not providing enough context for us to help you.

Comment: @LinusJuhlin Please check .I've updated the question again. I just want to show the props "message" that I'm getting in Vue inspector to Vue components

Comment: Your question is still too vague. There's a Inertia.js discord that you can find on the inertiajs.com website that you can join if you feel that might be easier.

Answer (score 2):

According to your question in your `vue component` you can define the data as  `props` and then you can show it in your `template` like the below example:

```
<script setup>

import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia';

const props = defineProps({
    message: {
        type: String
    },
});

</script>

<template>
    <div>{{props?.message}}</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

*I'm unsure about the phrasing of your question. I'm guessing that you mean you want to know how to use flashed data outside of when redirecting.*

## Passing data with Inertia.js

[Passing data to inertia is pretty straightforward](https://inertiajs.com/pages#creating-pages).

First you set up a controller method that returns an `inertia` response with the data you want to pass as a prop to your component.

```php
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        return inertia('ContactPage', [
            'message' => 'My message!',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then make setup your Vue.js component

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ message }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            message: String,
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then you are good to go! You should now be able to see `My message!`, when you go to the route corresponding to your controller.

## Flash message without redirect

Accessing flashed data in Inertia.js is not much more difficult than doing it in a vanilla Laravel app. You're on the the right track, but seem to be missing how flash data without using a redirect.

In Laravel the flashed data is stored in the [session on the request](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#flash-data). So if you want to set a message on the current request then you do it like so:

```php
request()->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
```

After this you just render Vue.js component [as per the Inertia.js docs](https://inertiajs.com/responses#creating-responses).

In your case it all would look something like this:

```php
public function contact_project(){
    $user = User::find(Auth::id())->has_many_through_projects_contents();
    $message = $user->paginate(1);

    request()->session()->flash('message', $message);

    return inertia('Contact_to_project');
}
```

Then you access it like you mentioned in your question.

```
<div v-if="$page.props.flash.message" class="alert">
    {{ $page.props.flash.message }}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not accessing the property the right way.
Since **props** is the wrapper for all of the data you send from the server, the way you access them is by using props first.

```
<template> {{props.message}}</template>
```

Comment: When I do that I got error _ctx.props is undefined
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ctx.props is undefined"

Comment: This is not helpful. This goes against how accessing props is done in both vue and for shared data in inertia.js.